Symfony 6.4 LTS - issue with Doctrine DBAL dependency
Working on Symfony 6.4 (LTS) application, which worked like a charm. I regularly run "composer update" and checked on recipes of course, too.
And I don't know what happened but with the composer.json below I now get the following statement during composer update (or install):

Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine-dbal for package doctrine/dbal: file not found in package

and during cache:clear I get:
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError {#45
!!    #message: """
!!      Attempted to load class "Configuration" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL".\n

Already deleted vendor, cache etc., tried to re-install. Tried to find any incorrect/conflicting dependencies, but I was unsuccessful so far. I can exclude to use anything Doctrine DBAL config related directly in my source code.
Here my composer.json which as well is mostly standard (no crazy stuff from my side):
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.4",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.32",
        "symfony/asset": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.20",
        "symfony/string": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/ux-turbo": "^2.20",
        "symfony/validator": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.4.*"
        },
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Calendar"
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.4.*"
    }
}


I can install and update from the above composer.json without issue.
